# how to connect android to local pc through socket

Tags: android

this is a general question and requires no coding for now.I am using shareGps app in android and I am transfering its data to my pc threw usb tethering via adb bridge hack. it forwards a tcp port to receive the data. I forwarded the port to 50000 using `adb forward tcp:50000 tcp:50000`
now the shareGps app also is connected to the socket 127.0.0.1:50000

problem is when I use any other port other than 50000.whenever I try to use another port other than 50000,it doesnot contains the gps data. why??? also help me with a workaround to it if you can

EDIT:

I also want to know which port the android application "ShareGps" is listening to and also i want to change the port it is using. help me with that if it is possible

Comment: What port did you try? Was it in the unprivileged range? Was the software on both the PC and the Android device set to use that same alternative port?  BTW what you are describing is not "tethering" in the popular sense of the word, though obviously the USB cable can be considered a physical tether on the device.

Comment: i did try to know the port number which the shareGps is using.I tried running `netstat-a` in terminal emulator in android which output the port used but it did not contained the port upper than 10000.how come 50000??

Comment: Probably because that is the port the author of that app chose to use.  You should probably contact support for that app; this doesn't really seem to be or likely to become a programming question, so it's not a good fit here.

Comment: it is programming question as I also want to change the port the application is using programmatically. one way to change that is to create virtual port. so how can i make a virtual port programmatically or how could i assign already and open/unused port to an application?

Comment: You can't.  If the port is hardcoded in the application (vs adjustable in a settings menu), on the android side that is the port is it going to use.  You can however change the port number on the PC side of the forward when you set that up with adb.

Comment: thanks a lot.confusion gone..now only 1 query remaining...how can i know which port to the particular application in android is listening to???

Comment: Read its documentation.  But didn't  you already find that with netstat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must know the range of ports: [List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers)

**Dynamic, private or ephemeral ports.**
The range 49152–65535 - above the registered ports - contains dynamic or private ports that cannot be registered with IANA. This range is used for custom or temporary purposes and for automatic allocation of ephemeral ports.

As You can see in the userGuide of application: [sharedroid.jillybunch.com/user.html](http://sharedroid.jillybunch.com/user.html) ,You can just use 500000 for shareGps tcp port

Comment: if that is so, then i think port 50000 might be the port sharegps is using.am i right here??? how can i know which port is the application "shareGps" is listening to???

Comment: As You can see in the userGuide of application: http://sharedroid.jillybunch.com/user.html ,You can just use 500000 for shareGps tcp port.